# Tooltip for ListBoxItem When binded to List of strings

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, tooltip

How can we show tooltip for a ListBoxItem when ListBox control is binded to List of strings. Below, is the source code for my ListBox, where ConcernedConditions is of List type.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ConcernedConditions}" Style="{StaticResource CustomStyle}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template"> 
                <Setter.Value> 
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"> 
                        <ContentPresenter /> 
                    </ControlTemplate> 
                </Setter.Value> 
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you style the item template of the listbox and put a textblock in there, then use it's tooltip property?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" ToolTip="Here is a tooltip"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Wow... that was really an easy fix. Thanks Andy :)